# What is an example of a topology and set such that $\partial\partial S \subsetneq \partial S$?

Tags: general-topology

I understand the proof that for any topological space $(X,\mathscr T)$ and set $S\subseteq X$, the containment $\partial \partial S\subseteq \partial S$ holds.  However, I can't think of an example which proves that the inequality is strict.  I know that for any open set, and for any closed set, equality holds so you can't look for examples like those.  This tells me that we don't want to look for examples in the discrete topology, and even the Sierpinski topology every subset is either open or closed.  In the real numbers with the standard topology don't work.  An isolated point is its own boundary, and as far as I can tell, the boundary of any set in the real numbers is always a set of isolated points or is empty.  I've tried thinking of a few other finite topologies through more or less brute force, and I've tried to think of the reals with the topology of open rays to the right (i.e. open sets are of the form $(a,\infty)$ for $a\in\Bbb R$.)  But so far no luck.

Comment: Consider $S = \mathbb Q$ in $X = \mathbb R$ with the standard topology.

Comment: @Rushy Ah, I considered that but mis-calculated it!  Thanks!